# Custom seekBar background is not matching with its foreground

Tags: android, seekbar

I am trying to make custom `seekBar` like this.[image]

Here is my **code**:

```
<SeekBar
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_seek_bar" />
```

custom_seek_bar.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_grey" />
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_black" />
</item>
```

But the grey-colored seekbar and black-colored seekBar are not matching after doing that. Please help me in solving this.

Here is seekbar_black.
[image: seelbar_black]

Here is seekbar_grey.
[image: seekbar_grey]

This image is final output. background and foreground are not matching.
[image: not matching problem]

Comment: remove the clip tag from custom_seek_bar.xml [work for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uN5Kl.png).

Comment: Thanks alot dude. It works for me too instead of clip tag, I use background for item progress too. @MohamedMohaideenAH